# Powermock with Mockito

Tags: java, android, mockito, powermock

Im trying to use PowerMock with Mockito, but PowerMock.replayAll(); and PowerMock.verifyAll(); is not found in my Eclipse environment. Used this download link:

```
http://code.google.com/p/powermock/downloads/detail?name=powermock-mockito-junit-1.5.zip&can=2&q=
```

And downloaded EasyMock here:

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/easymock/files/EasyMock/3.1/easymock-3.1.zip/download
```

Added all the jars to my libs directory (removed it from my build path). Anyone? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Source code Android project and test project:

```
https://github.com/powder366/test
https://github.com/powder366/testtest
```

example.

```
package com.test

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.PowerMockUtils;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Greeter.class)
public class MockStaticExampleTest {
    @Test
    public void mockStaticExample() throws Exception {
        String expectedGreeting = "greeting";
        String nameToGreet = "name";

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Greeter.class);
        EasyMock.expect(Greeter.getGreeting(nameToGreet)).andReturn(expectedGreeting);
        PowerMock.replayAll();

        String actualGreeting = Greeter.getGreeting(nameToGreet);

        PowerMock.verifyAll();
        assertEquals("Expected and actual greeting did not match", expectedGreeting, actualGreeting);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the title you say "PowerMock with Mockito". In the question body you mentioned Easymock. Which library are you trying to extend with PowerMock: Mockito or EasyMock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally downloaded:

```
http://code.google.com/p/powermock/downloads/detail?name=powermock-easymock-1.5-full.jar&can=2&q=
```

and it worked with PowerMock.replayAll(); and PowerMock.verifyAll();

Answer (score 0):

You have not to add your `jars` to the `Eclipse` build path, but you have to place the `jars` inside the `libs` folder. `ADT` will do what takes to import it.

Comment: you missed to add dexmaker.jar. Does it no more needed?

Comment: Im not sure but I tried it and no difference. Got the dexmaker from http://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/downloads/detail?name=dexmaker-mockito-1.0.jar&can=2&q=

Comment: maybe is Eclipse messing with the build path. Could try to create a new test project ?

Comment: Same thing, uploaded the source.

Comment: I finally downloaded: http://code.google.com/p/powermock/downloads/detail?name=powermock-easymock-1.5-full.jar&can=2&q= and it worked with PowerMock.replayAll(); and PowerMock.verifyAll();